# Is there a way to tell puppet to only execute command if one of the files does not exist?

Tags: automation, puppet

I would like to create openvpn certificates with puppet. I have a script that creates these certs, but I would like to execute it only if necessary. The manifest looks like this:

```
[...]
$keydir = ['/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys']
$usercerts = ["$keydir/user1.crt", "$keydir/user2.crt"]

exec { 'build-keys':
  command => '/opt/openvpn/build-keys',

  creates => $usercerts,

  notify  => Service['openvpn'],
}
[...]
```

First it creates the certifications, but if I modify the usercerts variable, it won't start the script anymore. 
Is there any restriction, that the creates parameter cannot handle arrays? 
Does puppet block execution if any of these files exist or if all of them? 
Should I create a script to check if these files exist and put it into onlyif?

Comment: It should Just Work. What version of Puppet (agent) is this?

Comment: The puppet version on the node is 2.7.23

Comment: OK, that should suffice. Have you tried running with the `-dv` flags?

Comment: It indicates, that the Exec[build-keys] has been noticed, but it does not run. I posted the results below:

notice: /Stage[main]/Openvpn::Keygen/Exec[build-keys]: Would have triggered 'refresh' from 1 events

debug: /Stage[main]/Openvpn::Keygen/Exec[build-keys]: The container Class[Openvpn::Keygen] will propagate my refresh event

info: /Stage[main]/Openvpn::Keygen/Exec[build-keys]: Scheduling refresh of Service[openvpn]

Comment: Hm, still unclear. Finally, have you made very sure that the current value of `$usercerts` does not indicate files that **do** already exist on the agent system?

Comment: I created a previously absent user, and started the puppet agent. It didn't execute the script

Comment: Does the elements of the array have disjunction or conjunction relationship?

Comment: If I call the script having only one (previously excluded) user, the script starts to generate the cert. Yet if any other existing user is included in the usercerts array, the puppet agent does not bother itself with the generation

Comment: Ah, so the presence of any one of the files is enough to keep the exec from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be doing this in a class.

```
define openvpn_keys($username=$name, $keydir = '/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys') {

    $usercert = "$keydir/$username.crt"

    exec { "build-keys-for-$username":
       command => '/opt/openvpn/build-keys',
       creates => $usercert,
       notify  => Service['openvpn'],
    }
}
```

Then use this via

```
openvpn_keys {
   [ "user1", "user2" ]:
}
```